# IF function in PostgreSQL as in MySQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, case, plpgsql

I am trying to replicate the `IF` function from MySQL into PostgreSQL.

The syntax of `IF` function is `IF(condition, return_if_true, return_if_false)`

I created following formula:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION if(boolean, anyelement, anyelement)
   RETURNS anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN ($1) THEN
    RETURN ($2);
    ELSE
    RETURN ($3);
    END CASE;
    EXCEPTION WHEN division_by_zero THEN
    RETURN ($3);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It works well with most of the things like `if(2>1, 2, 1)` but it raises an error for:

```
if( 5/0 > 0, 5, 0)
```

> fatal error division by zero.

**In my program I can't check the denominator as the condition is provided by user.**

Is there any way around? Maybe if we can replace first parameter from boolean to something else, as in that case the function will work as it will raise and return the exception.

Comment: What's wrong with using a `CASE` statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name They appear to be accepting the expression, like `5/0`, straight from the user so they can't split it up and inspect it or transform it with `CASE`. SQL-injection-tastic.

Comment: @wildplasser: Unwise, but "legal". [The keyword is not reserved](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can't use case cause:

1) Migrating existing MySQL project where conditions are provided by users.
2) IF() is standard condition function from Excel (and the users are not programmers but Excel users).

Comment: ad 2) : "if" is a four-letter-word in sanskrit. It might be offensive to others too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### PostgreSQL is following the standard

This behaviour appears to be [specified by the SQL standard](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2009-07/msg01420.php). This is the first time I've seen a case where it's a real problem, though; you usually just use a `CASE` expression or a PL/PgSQL `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block to handle it.

MySQL's default behaviour is dangerous and wrong. It only works that way to support older code that relies on this behaviour. It has been [fixed in newer versions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_error_for_division_by_zero) when [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html) is active (which it absolutely always should be) but unfortunately has not yet been made the default. When using MySQL, always enable `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` or `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`.

ANSI-standard zero division is a pain sometimes, but it'll also protect against mistakes causing data loss.

### SQL injection warning, consider re-design

If you're executing expressions from the user then you quite likely have [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems. Depending on your security requirements you might be able to live with that, but it's pretty bad if you don't totally trust all your users. Remember, [your users could be tricked into entering the malicious code from elsewhere](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Consider re-designing to expose an expression builder to the user and use a query builder to create the SQL from the user expressions. This would be much more complicated, but secure.

If you can't do that, see if you can parse the expressions the user enters into an abstract syntax, validate it before execution, and then produce new SQL expressions based on the parsed expression. That way you can at least limit what they can write, so they don't slip any nasties into the expression. You can also rewrite the expression to add things like checks for zero division. Finding (or writing) parsers for algebraic expressions isn't likely to be hard, but it'll depend on what kinds of expressions you need to let users write.

At minimum, the app needs to be using a role ("user") that has only `SELECT` privileges on the tables, is not a superuser, and does not own the tables. That'll minimise the harm any SQL injection will cause.

### CASE won't solve this problem as written

In any case, because you currently don't validate and can't inspect the expression from the user, you can't use the SQL-standard `CASE` statement to solve this. For `if( a/b > 0, a, b)` you'd usually write something like:

```
CASE
    WHEN b = 0 THEN b
    ELSE CASE 
        WHEN a/b=0 THEN a
        ELSE b
    END
END
```

This explicitly handles the zero denominator case, but is only possible when you can break the expression up.

### Ugly workaround #1

An alternative solution would be to get Pg to return a placeholder instead of raising an exception for division by zero by defining a replacement division operator or function. This will only solve the divide-by-zero case, not others.

I wanted to return `'NaN'` as that's the logical result. Unfortunately, 'NaN' is greater than numbers not less then, and you want a less-than or false-like result.

```
regress=# SELECT NUMERIC 'NaN' > 0;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

This means we have to use the icky hack of returning NULL instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION div_null_on_zero(numeric,numeric) returns numeric AS $$
VALUES (CASE WHEN $2 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE $1/$2 END)
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR @/@ (
    PROCEDURE = div_null_on_zero(numeric,numeric),
    LEFTARG = numeric,
    RIGHTARG = numeric
);
```

with usage:

```
regress=# SELECT 5 @/@ 0, 5 @/@ 0>0, CASE WHEN 5 @/@ 0 > 0 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END;
 ?column? | ?column? | case 
----------+----------+------
          |          |    0
(1 row)
```

Your app can rewrite '/' in incoming expressions into `@/@` or whatever operator name you choose pretty easily.

There's one pretty critical problem with this approach, and that's that `@/@` will have different precedence to `/` so expressions without explicit parentheses may not be evaluated as you expect. You might be able to get around this by creating a new schema, defining an operator named `/` in that schema that does your null-on-error trick, and then adding that schema to your `search_path` before executing user expressions. It's probably a bad idea, though.

### Ugly workaround #2

Since you can't inspect the denominator, all I can think of is to wrap the whole thing in a [`DO` block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) (Pg 9.0+) or PL/PgSQL function and catch any exceptions from the evaluation of the expression.

[Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12414969/398670) provides a better example of this than I did, so I've removed this. In any case, this is an awful and dangerous thing to do, do not do it. Your app needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks Craig for guidelines and tips. Following the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" approach, will probably stay with MySql for the moment. Replacing core function is an nice workaround but it might lead to a whole ugly chain of such replacements. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Pratyush I strongly recommend that you start fixing your app up so it can run under `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and/or `ANSI` mode in MySQL. It'll save you from some nasty gotchas and make it easier to port to other DBs.

Comment: @Pratyush Also, you *REALLY* need to fix your SQL injection hole. Seriously, redesign. Parse the user's expression, and then use the parse tree to generate safe and valid SQL. Do not just paste the user's expression directly into the SQL. Since I assume you're using PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 9):

With a boolean argument, a division by zero will always throw an exception (and that's a good thing), *before* your function is even called. There is **nothing** you can do about it. It's already happened.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION if(boolean, anyelement, anyelement)
 RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
SELECT CASE WHEN $1 THEN $2 ELSE $3 END
$func$;
```

I would **strongly advise against** a function named `if` to begin with. `IF` is a keyword in PL/pgSQL. If you use user defined functions written in PL/pgSQL this will be very confusing.

Just use the standard SQL expression [**`CASE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) directly.

---

The alternative would be to take a **`text` argument** and evaluate it with [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

#### Proof of concept

What you ask for would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_if(_expr text
                              , _true anyelement
                              , _else anyelement
                              , OUT result anyelement)
  RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
   SELECT CASE WHEN (' || _expr || ') THEN $1 ELSE $2 END' -- !! dangerous !!
   USING _true, _else
   INTO result;

   EXCEPTION WHEN division_by_zero THEN
   result := _else;
   -- possibly catch more types of exceptions ...
END
$func$;
```

Test:

```
SELECT f_if('TRUE'   , 1, 2)  --> 1
      ,f_if('FALSE'  , 1, 2)  --> 2
      ,f_if('NULL'   , 1, 2)  --> 2
      ,f_if('1/0 > 0', 1, 2); --> 2
```

This is a big **security hazard** in the hands of untrusted users. Read @Craig's answer about making this more secure.
However, I fail to see how it can be made bulletproof and would never use it.

Comment: Btw: MySQL would not suffer from the division by zero problem as it actually allows that (and returns NULL). Maybe that's the reason the `if` is working in MySQL in the first place.

Comment: @muistooshort: Sometimes it's hard to suppress the rant. [MySQL is so creative](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PoFIohBSM4) ... but you are right, it shouldn't go into an answer, that's not helping. So I restrain myself.

Comment: I don't think that pointing out suppressing divide-by-zero errors is a mistake is a rant. The poster wants to do something fundamentally mistaken in the absence of sophisticated NaN-based support for division by zero. MySQL's design has traditionally favoured immediate gratification over long-term data integrity and it is entirely responsible for an experienced DBA to point out that this sort of thing is generally a bad thing.

Comment: Unfortunately `CASE` won't work here, because they're accepting an expression as-is from the user. Terrible idea in the 1st place, but CASE won't fix it.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I addressed that briefly in my last paragraph. But I wasn't going to elaborate further. As you said, terrible idea. The OP should try a completely different approach if at all possible.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I understand the concerns of MySQL but it is a specific need of the project to use IF function. To prevent injection, the user query is checked for malicious commands. Raising fatal error in case of "division by zero" is over strict on part of PostgreSQL. It should provide NaN which may be then taken care of by the programmer.

Comment: @Pratyush: OK, so I added a function that does the job. I am still advising against using it.

Comment: @Pratyush PostgreSQL is only doing what the SQL standard requires, and what most databases other than MySQL do by default. MySQL only works the way it does because in the bad old days it originally didn't support transactions, so it had no way to abort an operation half-done and had to use workarounds to avoid producing errors when it should've. That's why it does daft things like accepts '0000-00-00' as a legal date, too. Now, MySQL (when in strict mode with InnoDB, which it always should be) works just like PostgreSQL and raises an exception.